# Align div element to the right side withour overlapping

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="border: 1px solid">Hello</div>
<div style="float: right;border: 1px solid;width: 30%">Centre</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid">World</div>
```

I am trying to align the second div to the right side because its only 30% of the width. However when I use float the 3rd div overlaps with the second one. How do I make sure that the 3rd div comes only after the 2nd div not immediately after 1st div. Text-align wouldn't help because I want the entire div  to be in the right side not just the content of it.

Please suggest.

Comment: have you tried clear:both; on the third div ? This removes the floating of everything that was before.

Comment: Where do you want the third Div?

Comment: It worked ! But I did not understand if it removed floating , why do I have to use float at all. is there way to align div to the right without making it float ? Also hope clear:both with not affect any other floating in the page ?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me in dreamweaver but not in jsfiddle for some reason? Please leave a comment if you know why.

http://jsfiddle.net/WAWN2/

```
<div style="border: 1px solid; width:100%">Hello</div>
<div style="float: right;border: 1px solid; width:30%; display:block;">Centre</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid; width:100%">World</div>​
```

Also here is an example using clear:both

http://jsfiddle.net/NyFGB/

Answer (score 0):

Move the second div above the first in the html in order to get the layout the way you want it:

```html
<div style="float: right;border: 1px solid;width: 30%">Centre</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid">Hello</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid">World</div>
```